# How to use the `path` function instead of the `url` function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am learning how to use django-rest-framework to build my front-end separation project. I follow the django official documentation using the `path` function instead of the `url` function for development. But when I added django-rest-framework, I found that django-rest-framework is still using the `url` function. In order to maintain code consistency, I wrote the following code:

In 'quickstart/urls.py'('quickstart' is my app name)

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register('groups', views.GroupViewSet)

app_name = 'quickstart'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

In 'tutorial/urls.py'('tutorial' is project name)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('quickstart/', include('quickstart.urls')),
]
```

However, there was a problem with the program. When I visited 127.0.0.1/quickstart/users, I got the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /quickstart/users/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 376, in to_representation
    url = self.get_url(value, self.view_name, request, format)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 314, in get_url
    return self.reverse(view_name, kwargs=kwargs, request=request, format=format)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\reverse.py", line 50, in reverse
    url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\reverse.py", line 63, in _reverse
    url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-detail' not found. 'user-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 48, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 765, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 683, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 683, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 527, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "C:\dev\tomorrow-headline\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 391, in to_representation
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg % self.view_name)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
[17/Aug/2018 10:33:18] "GET /quickstart/users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 151754
```

This code is completely written in the official django-rest-framework tutorial, just a simple modification of the 'urls' file. So my question is: how to replace the `url` function with the `path` function? Do I need to modify the code in other parts?

Edit====================

I change the code in tutorial/urls.py:

from `path('quickstart/', include('quickstart.urls')),` to

```
from quickstart import urls 
...
path('quickstart/', include(urls.urlpatterns)),
```

This code works fine, but why?

========================

Thank's a lot.

Comment: My python version is 3.6.6, django 2.1, rest-framework 3.8.2.

Comment: Did you include rest_framework in settings.py?

Comment: Yes, I added `'rest_framework'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in tutorial/settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using `Django==2.0.5` and `djangorestframework==3.8.2`.

I'm  not facing any issue while using url. My code is working absolutely as a charm. I would recommend you not to change *url* to *path*.
Following is an example from my codebase

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^abc/', include('abc.urls', namespace="abc")),
    url(r'^xyz/', include('xyz.urls', namespace="xyz")),
]
```

**abc/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import *

app_name = 'abc'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^update_xyz', update_xyz, ),
]
```

Comment: The `url` function runs completely correctly. But I want to know if there is a way to use the `path` function to rewrite the rest framework tutorial.

Comment: could you add namespace and try `path('quickstart/', include('quickstart.urls', namespace="quickstart")),`

Comment: Then I would recommend you to work with url and move on until the drf team comes up with a proper update to work _path_. Also you might create a  issue in the github project.

Comment: Thank's a lot. I'll try to create a issue in there github project.

Answer (score 0):

After a period of study, my understanding of `Django` and `django-rest-framework` has gradually deepened. I found that the problem is not in the `url()` function and the `path()` function, but the view has a problem.

In my code, I used `ModelViewSet` to organize my view. I didn't add the `lookup_field` property when writing the `UserViewSet`. This causes the router to handle the request without knowing which url parameter to call the detail part of the `UserViewSet`.

In my code, I added the `lookup_field` property to fix this bug. Code show as below(`views.py`):

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from articles.models import Article
from articles.serializers import ArticleSerializer


class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

I did some refactoring work on the previous code, so the current code might look different from the previous one. But this is no big problem.